# Is there any way to get current timezone in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the client’s timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Is there anyway to get current timezone in javascript. All i see is

```
Date.getTimeZoneOffset()
```

The problem I am facing is, I have a piece of functionality which allows the users to download pdf, now the pdf has to include a 'download date' in it which should be users local date, have to do this in java. But its all confusing, I dont know if i should locale or not or just the timezone will work, each time when i try something the results are different!!!!

Comment: That would be the current timezone...

Comment: Do you mean the time zone name, such as "CET" or "Europe/Madrid"?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: @Shmiddty UTC offset is not a timezone, the offset changes depending on the computer's real timezone and the date object's value whereas a timezone like 'Europe/London' encapsulates the DST changes and offsets depending on time.

Comment: Please *don't close* this as a duplicate for that question without reading it through first; as the other question (and accepted answer) focus on the *offset* via `getTimeZoneOffset` which was mentioned in the question here ..

Comment: Seconded. The supplied duplicate's topic is offset. This question is about timezones (presumably Olson timezones e.g. "Europe/London").

Answer (score 7):

Use **[`Date.toTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString)**

**Code:**

```
var date = new Date();
document.write(date.toTimeString());
```

**Output:**

```
22:53:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
              ^offset     ^timezone
```

Comment: I get `new Date( 2012, 0 ).toTimeString(); //"00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)"` and `new Date( 2012, 6 ).toTimeString(); //00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)` which are not that useful, when a simple `Europe/Helsinki` would have encapsulated all of this in a single timezone.

Comment: @Esailija In any case, that library you mentioned will serve better. I was just trying to find that piece of information using built-in functions.

Comment: The problem I am facing is, I have a piece of functionality which allows the users to download pdf, now the pdf has to include a 'download date' in it which should be users local date, have to do this in java. But its all confusing, I dont know if i should locale or not or just the timezone will work, each time when i try something the results are different!!!!

Comment: If you are looking for the date, JS won't really be reliable. Can't use the server-side date?